# How do I change a file format when saving a Microsoft Word Doc programmatically?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently modifying a Microsoft Word doc to prompt the user to do something when they save.

After they select an answer, I want to save the document as a different file type, converting it specifically from a .docm to a .docx file.

```
 Sub FileSave()
 Dim myQ As Integer
 With ActiveDocument

    myQ = MsgBox("Is this the Final version of this document?  Clicking  'Yes' will permanently disable macros for moving issues and remove the blank final page.", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
    If myQ = vbYes Then
      .SaveAs2 ActiveDocument.Name & ".docx"
      DeleteFinalPage
    Else
       .SaveAs2 ActiveDocument.Name
    End If

    End With

 End Sub
```

As you can see, this saves the document as "DocumentNameHere.docm.docx"

How exactly do I go about getting rid of that nasty .docm in the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use file extension to indicate file type. Don't use a fixed number of chars to remove an extension - this will fail for old fashioned .doc (instead of .docm). Use InStrRev. This is designed for things like this.

Strip the extension off, then save as your desired type using the argument specifically intended for this purpose: FileFormat.

`doc.SaveAs2 Left(doc.Name, InStrRev(doc.Name, ".") - 1), wdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument`

Comment: This literally fixed my is question from before.  You guys rock!  Thanks!  I'm assuming just changing the extension doesn't modify any of the internal junk that makes a .docx and a .docm different?  Which is why we use the FileFormat to convert it?

Comment: @Arcus glad it helped. You are correct - file extension just associates a file with an application in Windows. However, Word won't let you open/save files into a format that differs to its extension (for various reasons, primarily for security reasons)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the .docm I would do

`.saveAs2 left(ActiveDocument.Name,len(ActiveDocument.Name)-5)`

This will take off the last 5 characters of the `ActiveDocument.Name` leaving just the document name not the extension.

Comment: This worked and it didn't.  I stupidly thought you could just change the extension and everything would be okay.  However, after I changed the extension and opened up the new .docx file I got this:

"The file FileNameHere.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.

Details?